# "{This / That} is the essence of our brand."

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

Since I’m not native English, I was hoping that someone could help me out with the following question.

I have a slogan that says:

> *When people envision… , they think of…*
>
> **That / This**  *is the essence of our brand.*

I’m not sure which of the two (that / this) is the best choice to use here, and would love to know why one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use **this**.

**This** signifies something which is **closer** to you
**That** signifies something which is **further** from you

Your **brand** is something **very close** to you

**That** is the essence of **their** brand, but **this** is the essence of **our** brand.

Comment: Thank you for your time and clear answer Peter! :) Have a great day ahead.